# How to focus text input on transition end?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

If the Mui Collapsible has extended I want to show a text input that is focused. The autofocus property does not work. Is there away to achive the focus?

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8njup?file=/demo.js)

```
    <Collapse in={checked}>
        <input autofocus type="text" />
    </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a ref to input element and make it focused in the `useEffect` according to the value of `checked`.
[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-l98pn?file=/demo.js)

```
export default function SimpleCollapse() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
  const textInput = React.useRef(null);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setChecked((prev) => !prev);
  };
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (checked) {
      textInput.current.focus();
    }
  }, [checked]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <FormControlLabel
        control={<Switch checked={checked} onChange={handleChange} />}
        label="Show"
      />
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <Collapse in={checked}>
          <Paper elevation={4} className={classes.paper}>
            <input ref={textInput} type="text" />
          </Paper>
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```